# Type Mismatch : can not convert from element type to PlayList<Song>

Tags: java

Type Mismatch : can not convert from element type to PlayList

```
PlayList<Song> p1 = new PlayList<Song>(s1);

for (PlayList<Song> s: p1.toList()){ // Error here (Type Mismatch)
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Let's see the implementation of `PlayList`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `toList()` returns a `List<Song>`, you're just misunderstanding what the [enhanced `for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) does.  Declare the looping variable to be the element type, not the list type:

```
for (Song s : p1.toList()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
for (Song s: p1.toList()){
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (Song s : p1.toList()){ 
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

It should work OK.